# Python can create large dicts in memory but can not load them from a file

Tags: python, dictionary

My work involves creating look up tables with python `defaultdict(set)`. Building all of these dicts takes about 20 minutes and uses about 2GB of ram. I am trying to save time by writing all of these dicts to a `.py` file and then loading them back in with an import.

I'm writing the file with `theFile.write("idToName = {}\n".format(dict(idToName)))` to remove the set part of the `defaultdict` class. The file is about 500MB and the dicts all work fine. However, when I try to import the file back in it fills my ram and locks everything up. What would be causing this difference in ram usage?

Comment: well, memory usage is a thing, but whatever the reason don't do this. You better to save dicts as JSON (`import json; json.dump(dictname, filehandler)`).

Comment: Have you considered writing/reading to a JSON file instead? Using the json module.

Comment: I thought that the dicts were already basically json so I could import them already. It's also interesting that this was working at some point but I will try out JSON and report back

Comment: Set is not serializable...

Comment: A simple fix might be to switch to a 64-bit build of Python so you don't have a 2GB limit any more.

Comment: It's possible that the compiler is having trouble dealing with such a large single literal. You might consider writing out individual literals to build up the dictionary one key at a time.

Comment: Also, what are the data in the set? ints? strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you are scraping at the limit of your computer's RAM.  When you write a giant dictionary into a `.py` file, you have of course a gigantic `.py` file as well.  If you now try to import this, then the Python interpreter needs to do more than just hold the dictionary in memory.  It needs to open the source file, read it, compile it, write its bytecode representation (the compile result) to the `.pyc` file, then execute it which will finally create the dictionary in memory again.  All this means holding the data in more than one format in memory at the same time.

I think your approach is flawed.  Data should not be stored by writing `.py` files.  It is much better to store it using a technique called *serializing*, also called *marshalling* sometimes, and, in case of Python, also called `pickling` because it can be done with the standard module `pickle` (or `cPickle` for better performance).

You should store your *values* (the dictionaries) using the `pickle` module after creation of the values.  Then when you need them again, read the *values* again from the pickle store file:

```
import pickle
value = create_my_huge_dictionary()
with open('my_dictionary.pickle', 'w') as store_file:
    pickle.store(store_file, value)
```

Then later, maybe in a different script:

```
import pickle
with open('my_dictionary.pickle') as store_file:
    value = pickle.load(store_file)
```

Remains the topic about the `defaultdict` you want to strip.  The method mentioned above won't do that.  Storing a `defaultdict` in a pickle file and reading the value again from there will recreate a `defaultdict`, not a `dict`.

My proposal would be to live with that because it probably won't hurt to have a `defaultdict` instead of a dict.  But just in case this isn't feasible, you should consider to just not use `defaultdict`s in the first place.  You can achieve their feature by using normal `dict`s with this pattern:

```
d = {}
d.setdefault('a', {}).setdefault('b', 4)
# d will now be {'a': {'b': 4}}
```

Of course you could try to *convert* your `defaultdict` into a `dict` before or after pickling it.  You can do that by simply stating `d = dict(d)`.  But that would most certainly mean to have it for a short time twice in memory.  Maybe your RAM doesn't suffer that and you are stuck again.

If you use `json` for storing your dictionary (maybe it is simple enough for this), then the information that it once was a `defaultdict` also is gone after serializing it.

Comment: I don't need the defaultdict information after. I only use it so I don't insert duplicates.

Comment: Inserting duplicates?  `defaultdict` differs from `dict` insofar that it prepares a default value for each key which is read before being written.  It has nothing to do with duplicates.  Duplicates are handled likewise in `dict` as in `defaultdict` (i. e. just one entry is kept per key).

Comment: I use default to have each entry  be an empty set so I can just loop through the data once, duplicates get ignored because it's a set, and I don't have to worry about checking if the key has been inserted first

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what version of Python you are using, but python is probably at the limit to import a dict that large. If the dict takes up 2GB when created, you will need more than that to import it.

You are not using the right tools for the job. You should serialize your data to a file using the `pickle` module or use a database.

Or you can do something like this and make a lazy loading dict. That way you only get the item when you actually need it. PSUEDO CODE.

First make a shelf file from your dict.

```
def make_dict_shelf(my_dict, path):
        """
        Make a shelf for containing the items; this is typically only done when the dict is generated
        """
        s = shelve.open(path, "n", protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        for key, value in my_dict.items():
            s[key] = value
        s.close()
```

Lazy loading dict using python shelf.

```
def load_dict_shelf(my_lazy_dict, path):
        """
        Load the items from a python shelve via LazyLoadingDict as needed.
        """

class LazyLoadingDict(collections.MutableMapping):
            """
            Special dict that only loads items as they are accessed. If a item is accessed it gets copied from the
            shelve to the cache dict. All user items are saved in the cache ONLY. Saving data back to the shelf
            is currently NOT supported
            """
            def __init__(self, source):
                self.source = source  # python shelf
                self.cache = {}  # internal dict

            def __getitem__(self, key):
                # try to get the item from the cache, if it isn't there get it from the shelf
                try:
                    return self.cache[key]
                except KeyError:
                    node = self.cache[key] = self.source[key.to_string()]
                    return node

            def __setitem__(self, key, value):
                # add a new item to the cache; if this item is in the shelf it is not updated
                self.cache[key] = value

            def __contains__(self, key):
                return key in self.cache or key.to_string() in self.source

            def __delitem__(self, key):
                # only deleting items from the cache is allowed
                del self.cache[key]

            def __iter__(self):
                # only the cache can be iterated over
                return iter(self.cache.keys())

            def __len__(self):
                # only returns the length of items in the cache, not unaccessed items in the shelf
                return len(self.cache)

        my_lazy_dict._items = LazyLoadingDict(shelve.open(path, "r"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that met all my needs. The correct answer is because they did answer why my file wouldn't load in.

First, I used the `shelve` module to save my data to a file and used the variable names as keys to the shelve dict.

Then, to load it and use the data like I had been, I opened the shelve, created an empty class based on `object` then the magic:

```
nb = MyClass()
for k,v in shelv.items():
    setattr(nb,k,v)
```

And I could use `nb.idToName['1234']` everywhere like usual.

The data file is only 90MB and loads in 30 seconds. Much more tolerable.

Thanks to everyone who helped nudge me along!

Comment: It would be interesting to pickle your entire `nb` class and see what the performance is like.

Comment: @zerox1212 I went with shelve over pickle because pickle couldn't serialize the sets in the dicts